# Reload stream without undeploying

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I have a stream with a custom sink module. When the stream is deployed the module connects and reads properties from database. I want to refresh the module properties without undeploying the stream, i.e., if a change is made in the database I should be able to refresh the properties without undeploying the stream.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use some kind of out-of-band technique to trigger the module to refresh its properties.

Possibilities include a JMX MBean, some other inbound-channel-adapter wired to a control-bus, ...